# C# List the class property in lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am trying to create an extension method to list the properties in the lambda expression.

Let say there is a Class named Example

```
public class Example {
     Public string Name {get;set;}
     Public string Description {get;set;} 
}
```

the extension method can be something like below

```
public static void GetProperties<T>(this T obj) where T : new()
{

}
```

Expected usage :  `this.GetProperties<Example>(m=>m.`

so when i type m=>m. should display both the properties (Name,Description).

Comment: How does this relate to entity framework ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to used Func:

```
public static void GetProperties<T, V>(this T obj, Func<T, V selector) where T : new()
{

}
```

Usage:

```
Example ex = new Example();

ex.GetProperties(m => m.Name); // Func<Example, string>
ex.GetProperties(m => m.Description); // Func<Example, string>
```

I really didn't understand the expected behavior inside the method. But you mentioned `m.Name` and `m.Description`. So a property selector is your way.

`Func<Example, string>` is a function that accepts an `Example` input parameter and returns a `string` (which is the property in case of `Name` and `Description`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class PropertyUtility
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this T entity, Expression<Func<T, object>> exp)
    {
      if (exp.Body is MemberExpression) {
        return ((MemberExpression)exp.Body).Member.Name;
    }
    else {
        var op = ((UnaryExpression)exp.Body).Operand;
        return ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
    } 
  }
}
```

And use like this:

```
Example ex = new Example();
var property = ex.GetPropertyName(x => x.Description);
```

Comment: Why do we need to use `Expression` if the selector is not to used by a provider and is just intended to be used locally (Where `Func` would perfectly work )?

Comment: It's just an example, having the wanted method named `GetProperties` , most probably is that it is wanted to work with the property name, not the value..otherwise why would you pass it as a selector?
And a method called `Get..` should return somethig, right ?